# Twitter API: how to retrieve timeline including promoted or sponsored tweets?

Tags: rest, twitter

How can the timeline of the currently authenticated user be retrieved, including promoted or sponsored tweets? So that the experience is like the official Twitter client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ads (promoted Tweets) are not included in the Twitter API, so this is not possible. The only thing you can do is to retrieve the user's home timeline, which will omit the promoted Tweets.

Comment: This is my impression as well. Do you have a source documenting this behavior? Or is this by experience/observation?

Comment: This is by knowledge of working at Twitter on the API for the last 5 years :-) unfortunately no that is not specified in the docs, but we should improve that to be more clear.

Comment: Ah, I should have looked at your profile first :D Thanks for the info.